# Media not playing on Ubuntu installed on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, video, music, media

I can't play any media on Ubuntu installed on VirtualBox. Whenever I try to play a media file or a YouTube video, it remains stuck at 0:00. If I move the slider to another point, it remains stuck there.

I had been using Ubuntu on VirtualBox for some time and had no problem playing media files, but due to some other problem I reinstalled Ubuntu (on a new virtual machine). I have been having this problem since then. I reinstalled Ubuntu once again, but the problem persists.

Ubuntu Version: 16.04
VirtualBox Version: 5.1.4
Virtual Machine Memory: 2 GB
Virtual Machine Disk Size: 16 GB
Host OS: OS X 10.11.6

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same exact issue. Apart from youtube, I am also unable to play mp3 files with Audacious or Rhythmbox or other mp3 players: they remain stuck at 0:00.

Answer (score 1):

I found for me a solution at the [VirtualBox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=79360), where they seem ready to help. 
 Try to follow the same instructions I followed myself, that is:

1. Shut down the guest operative system (Ubuntu 16.04.1) 
   This should also close the Virtual Machine
2. Click `Settings` or right click the Virtual Machine and choose `Settings`
3. Go to the `Audio` section and select a different `Audio Controller`
4. Restart the Virtual Machine and test your new setting

This worked for me and I hope it will work for you too

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the amount of **video memory** assigned to your VM.

Source: Just had the same problem, moving the slider all the way to the right magically fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying!

I installed version 5.0.26 of VirtualBox. Though it's not the most elegant solution, it solved the problem.